# GAE not showing subdomains to add SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https

I have been trying to add subdomains with SSL support to my Google App Engine project. Currently I am using a custom domain with SSL support. (let's just call it "mydomain.org"). I was able to successfully add subdomains in app engine by going to my google cloud console --> app engine --> settings --> custom domains --> add a custom domain. I then added " *.mydomain.org " as a new custom domain.

With this addition my list of custom domains now looks like: "mydomain.org", "www.mydomain.org", and " *.mydomain.org " Using HTTP, all of these routed correctly to my app. Next step I tried was to add SSL support to the new custom domain. I clicked on the SSL Certificates tab and clicked on my SSL cert I uploaded a while back. In the SSL menu it only listed "mydomain.org" and "www.mydomain.org" in the list I can enable SSL for custom domains. SSL works for those two subdomains, but not " *.mydomain.org ".

I have tried removing the "*.mydomain.org" custom domain and adding it several times to no avail. Also had no luck trying "app.mydomain.org" and "api.mydomain.org" too. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: `*.mydomain.org` is not a valid subdomain (you can't ping a machine with such name), you need to add each subdomain explicitly - no wildcards.

Comment: it still won't allow me to add explicit domains like app.mydomain.org to have SSL though.

Comment: Select `mydomain.com` at step 1, then, at step 2, add the `app` subdomain to it; also make sure you delete the wildcard one if you stilll have it.