# Sub domain not listed in Google App Engine while enabling SSL for custom domains

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, google-cloud-platform

I have been trying to use my own SSL certificate on subdomains for my app in GAE. I have successfully created the certificate and was able to enable it for all but one subdomain.

Let's say my domain is domain.com. I was able to enable the SSL certificate for domain.com, www.domain.com, subdomain.domain.com but for some reason, www.subdomain.domain.com does not show in the list of potential custom domains for my certificate. In this situation, I can not access my website through https://www.subdomain.domain.com but can through https://subdomain.domain.com.

Also, I can activate a google managed certificate for this subdomain, making https://www.subdomain.domain.com accessible, but of course, this is not what I want. Any clue on how to make www.subdomain.domain.com visible in the domains list of my certificate in order to then be able to turn it on?

This post is reporting a similar issue than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242921/gae-not-showing-subdomains-to-add-ssl). Sadly, no one has provided an answer and I do not have enough reputation to comment on it...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-level domains may be tricky. Starting with the type of the certificate obtained. From [RFC 2818](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt) (emphasis mine):

> Names may contain the wildcard character * which is considered to
>   match any single domain name component or component fragment. **E.g.,
>   `*.a.com` matches `foo.a.com` but not `bar.foo.a.com`.** f*.com
>   matches foo.com but not bar.com.

I suspect this is what's causing your trouble. Google also mentions in [App Engine support for SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#app_engine_support_for_ssl_certificates):

> Wildcard certificates only support one level of subdomain.

When trying the google-managed certificate the certificate is likely generated exactly for the respective domain, not a wildcard one, thus not having the problem mentioned in the above quote.

The only way I can think of to get this working is to obtain a separate wildcard certificate for the each domain level. But that could be a problem if you direct users to sites at different domain levels, as the certificate would change.

Personally I'd just arrange my domain names to be contained into just one domain level and avoid all these issues. Maybe  with something like `www-subdomain.domain.com` instead of `www.subdomain.domain.com`?

Comment: You are right, I totally missed that information regarding the number of levels supported for wildcard certificates. That is probably it. 

I could indeed get another wildcard certificate for *.subdomain.domain.com, but that feels a bit overkill. Also, using www-subdomain won't do it in the sense that I am just worried that people try to access the website through https://www.subdomain.*, which won't be helped in that case.

Answer (score 1):

According to Google Cloud docs, with ensuring your right permission in the GCP console and verified ownership on all parent domain, you can access subdomains with your custom certificate.

Example:

- If the certificate is for `www.example.com` you can verify ownership of either `www.example.com` or `example.com`.
- If the certificate is for `www.example.com` and `sub.example.com` you can either verify ownership of both `www.example.com` and `sub.example.com`, or of `example.com`.
- If the certificate is for `*.example.com` you must verify ownership of `example.com`.

You can check [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl), mostly the section mentioned

> Using your own SSL certificates