# Map subdomain to specific service on app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I want to map `notification.api.example.co.uk` to a specific app engine service called `notification-api`

I've added a custom domain on app engine called `api.example.com` successfully, so was hoping the following `dispatch.yaml` would be sufficient:

```
dispatch:
  - url: "notification.api.example.co.uk/*"
    service: notification-api
```

I was hoping, therefore, any request, for example, a POST to `notification.api.example.co.uk/test-api` would route the request to service and render a response, but it doesn't reach the backend at all.

Is there something wrong in this routing, the docs are quite confusing?

Comment: Is the request reaching any of your services (`default` most likely)? Did you actually map `notification.api.example.co.uk` to your app/service?

Comment: Note that multi-level domains can be tricky, see possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51576595/4495081

Comment: @DanCornilescu the dispatch.yaml above produces the mapping of the domain to the service.

Comment: It routes the request to your service, yes, but only **if** the request reaches your app. But without mapping the domain to your app how would GAE know the request is for your app?

Comment: I see, so I've added the custom domain already via AE as shown here: https://imgur.com/HBb9GKJ

Answer (score 0):

You need to map a [wild card subdomain](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcard_mappings) to your app engine. We need to know that everything for api.example.co.uk goes to your app in order to route notifications.api.example.co.uk to you.

Comment: I've added the custom domain already via AE as shown here: imgur.com/HBb9GKJ

Comment: They are not wild card setups. If you use an online DNS checker, are you able to resolve notifications.api.domain.com to Google servers?