# Map custom subdomain to App Engine service

Tags: google-app-engine, custom-domain

I have read those [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49480940/app-engine-custom-domain-with-service) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656490/map-subdomain-to-specific-service-on-app-engine) about it and it seems we have done pretty much the same, and it still does not work.

What I would like to do is to have the url `sub.domain.com` going to my default App Engine service and `api.sub.domain.com` to go to my "api" App Engine service (both services under the same GCP project).

`sub.domain.com` is already registered like a custom domain in App Engine and when I go to `sub.domain.com` it works (I can see my home page).

But this homepage also makes ajax calls to api.sub.domain.com and those don't work: I get a `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` from Google Chrome.

We have a dispatch as follow:

```
  - url: api.sub.domain.com/*
    service: api
  - url: api-dot-myproject.appspot.com/*
    service: api
  - url: sub.domain.com/*
    service: default
  - url: myproject.appspot.com/*
    service: default
```

So I'm not sure if there is something to do on the DNS of `domain.com` or if it's about those wildcard things in CNAME entries (like explained in [murrayc blog post](https://www.murrayc.com/permalink/2017/10/15/google-app-engine-using-subdomains/)), or if it's something else.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#using_subdomains) :

> 1) Wildcard mappings are not supported for managed SSL certificates.
>
> 2) Some DNS providers might not work with wildcard subdomain mapping. In particular, a DNS provider must permit wildcards in CNAME host entries.

I think that one of those two could be the main root cause for your issue in this particular context, as you `dispatch.yaml` looks fine.

Also, do you have your `dispatch:` written before declaring your urls, and services? You have [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml#example) an example of what I am saying.

Comment: yes, we have the `dispatch:` line at the beginning ;-)