# Google App Engine custom subdomain mapping for a specific version

Tags: google-app-engine

By default, specific versions of an App Engine app are [routed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-requests-are-routed#routing_via_url) by URLs like `https://[VERSION_ID]-dot-[SERVICE_ID]-dot-[MY_PROJECT_ID].appspot.com`.

Is there any way to have something similar with a custom domain?

I currently have a subdomain mapping for my app configured with a CNAME DNS record pointing to `ghs.googlehosted.com` (my "naked" domain is not served by App Engine).  This allows serving the default version of my app from that subdomain, but I also want to be able to test new versions of the app using my domain (for various reasons such as sharing cookies, etc.)

For example, let's say my domain is `typeracer.com` and my custom domain mapping in App Engine is `data.typeracer.com`: I want to be able to access a specific version of my app at a URL like `https://[VERSION_ID].data.typeracer.com`.  Is there any way to do this?

I've looked at the App Engine docs for adding [wildcard subdomain mappings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcard_mappings) and using a [dispatch.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml).  However, it looks like that would work only for routing specific *services*, but not specific *versions* of the app.

Answer (score 2):

No, what you ask for exactly is not possible as the mapping is a (sub)domain per GAE service one, you cannot select a certain version of a service in the custom domain settings screen.

Sounds like may be attempting to implement different environments (say staging) based on service versions, which has some disadvantage, see [Continuous integration/deployment/delivery on Google App Engine, too risky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192557/continuous-integration-deployment-delivery-on-google-app-engine-too-risky/40193364#40193364)

If so you can try to implement them using different services instead, which:

- would allow you to map one (sub)domain per environment
- you'd avoid all drawbacks mentioned in the above-mentioned Q&A

The domain naming scheme you mentioned suggests variable nesting levels, which in itself can be problematic, see [Sub domain not listed in Google App Engine while enabling SSL for custom domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560362/sub-domain-not-listed-in-google-app-engine-while-enabling-ssl-for-custom-domains/51576595#51576595). Maybe try something like `https://data-[VERSION_ID].typeracer.com` instead of `https://[VERSION_ID].data.typeracer.com`?