# gcloud cli app engine domain mapping error

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to get multiple microservices to run on a single app engine of a single project. I am following this official documentation from GCP

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains

When I try to create a wild card mapping like this

```
gcloud app domain-mappings create '*.example.com'
```

So that GCP backend engines can match the request accordingly:

```
[VERSION_ID].[SERVICE_ID].example.com
```

I get the following error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.domain-mappings.create) INVALID_ARGUMENT: A managed certificate cannot be created on a wildcard domain mapping. Set `ssl_management_type` to `MANUAL` and retry the domain mapping creation. You can manually create an SSL certificate with `AuthorizedCertificates.CREATE` and map it to this domain mapping with `AuthorizedCertificates.UPDATE`.
```

Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like by default the command attempts to configure managed SSL certificates, which aren't compatible with wildcard domain mappings. From [Wildcard mappings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#wildcard_mappings):

> ```
> **Note**: Wildcard mappings are not supported for managed SSL certificates.
> ```

As the error message suggests you can disable that with an option. From [gcloud beta app domain-mappings create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/domain-mappings/create):

> ```
> --certificate-management=CERTIFICATE_MANAGEMENT
> ```
>
> Type of certificate management. 'automatic' will provision an SSL
>   certificate automatically while 'manual' requires the user to provide
>   a certificate id to provision. `CERTIFICATE_MANAGEMENT` must be one
>   of: `automatic`, `manual`.

So just try instead:

```
gcloud app domain-mappings create '*.example.com' --certificate-management=manual
```

I see a discrepancy: the error message mentions the `ssl_management_type` option while the doc page shows `certificate-management`. Try both if needed - it may be just an error or it may be a renamed option (which may or may not still be supported under the hood).

Of course, if you want SSL, you'd have to manage the SSL certificate(s) yourself (maybe using the `--certificate-id` option, documented on the same page?). In that case also check out the related [Google App Engine custom subdomain mapping for a specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272201/google-app-engine-custom-subdomain-mapping-for-a-specific-version/55273174#55273174) for potential implications of variable domain nesting.