# How to set up multiple URLs point to to the same flex App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

We got one Flex app engine running Python and would like to let multiple clients access the same codebase with their own Cloud SQL instance.

How can I set up the URL mapping, something like client1.app.mydomain.com, client2.app.mydomain.com, client3.app.mydomain.com and all pointing to the same single app engine and then connect to each cloud SQL instance for each client?

Thanks in advance.

Johnny

Comment: Can you show the code handling the connection to the SQL instance? Is the connection done inside a request handler code or outside it (a global connection)?

Comment: I'm not sure, does it matter? first I want to know can the app engines allow custom URL for each client and that point to the same codebase in a single app engines services.

Comment: You can definitely map multiple sub-domains to the same app, but with care - all of them of the `*.app.mydomain.com` style (i.e. `app.mydomain.com` being your custom domain) or maybe using `client*-app.mydomain.com` style, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51576595/4495081. I'm not sure if there's a limit as to how many sub-domains are allowed - none is mentioned in the docs.